# How can I send some initial data to the bot before the user start chatting with my bot?

Tags: botframework, client-side, custom-data-attribute, web-chat

My problem is, How can I send some data on behalf of user to the bot before user start chatting.

because different client will have different endpoint, I would like bot to get this endpoint first and save it as UserState, then use this endpoint for making API calls later.

I'm using "https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat" this web chat as my client side, it create the directline using the secret, is that possible i add a post activity in the html file below to send some data?

Thank you！

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <body>
>     <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
>     <script src="Scripts/Directline.js"></script>
>     <script>
>         window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
>             directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
>                 token: 'my secret'
>             }),
>             locale: 'en-US',
>             botAvatarInitials: 'Bot',
>             userAvatarInitials: 'ME',
>         },
>         document.getElementById('webchat'));
>     </script> </body> </html>
> ```

Comment: Hope you got it working. If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" it so I can clear this ticket from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Comment: were you able to get this working?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a custom middleware to Web Chat's store which can send an event containing the necessary data to the bot when the DirectLine connection is fulfilled.  See the code snippets below.

**Web Chat**

```
const store = window.WebChat.createStore({},
  ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {

    if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
      // Send event to bot with custom data
      dispatch({
        type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
        payload: {
          name: 'webchat/join',
          value: { data: { username: 'TJ'}}
        }
      })
    }
    return next(action);
  });        


window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
store,
}, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

**Bot - C# SDK**

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using  Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Bots
{
    public class EchoBot : ActivityHandler
    {
        protected override async Task OnEventAsync(ITurnContext<IEventActivity> context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (context.Activity.Name == "webchat/join") {
                var data = JObject.Parse(context.Activity.Value.ToString()).GetValue("data");
                var user = JObject.Parse(data.ToString()).GetValue("username");
                await context.SendActivityAsync($"Hi, {user}!");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

For more details, take at the [Send Backchannel Welcome Event](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/3aba60483eea016816b2423a0dfcf529120324a2/samples/15.d.backchannel-send-welcome-event) Web Chat sample.

Hope this helps!