# What is the best way to pass contextual information from a web app to bot-framework

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a web application where users can raise or view IT tickets. I developed a chat bot using  Microsoft Bot Framework and C# to support specific cases. I embedded the bot with my website using an iframe from this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). Now i want to pass contextual information to my bot. For example when a user clicks on the web-chat i want to pass the user name and ticket it. What is the best way to do this?

I am aware that you can get specific channel data from several channels such as Slack or Facebook but is there a way to create my own custom channel?

Comment: Hope you got it working. If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" it so I can clear this ticket from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WebChat v4 you can add data to any outgoing activity's channel data through a custom store middleware; however, this approach does not work with the embedded iFrame. You have to either use a CDN or React.

For more details, take at the [Send Backchannel Welcome Event](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/a.welcome-event) Web Chat sample and this [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56294722/how-can-i-send-some-initial-data-to-the-bot-before-the-user-start-chatting-with).

#### Custom store without arrow functions

```js
function(ref) {
  const dispatch = ref.dispatch;
  return function (next) {
    return function(action) {
        if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
          dispatch({
            type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
            payload: {
                name: 'webchat/join',
                value: { language: window.navigator.language }
            }
          });
        return next(action);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to create the custom store without arrow functions? I tried converting to normal functions but it didn't work. We have a requirement for this to work in IE11 but it doesn't support arrow functions. I made updates in other areas of the code and am using the webchat-es5.js but the store is not working.

Comment: @billoverton I updated my question to include how to create a custom store without arrow functions.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't currently send any hidden information through the Web Chat channel.

What you can do is use the `DirectLine` channel along with the [WebChat web control](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat).  Then you can pass arbitrary data like your name and ticket id in the channel data object like is described in this [sign-on experiences example](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/08/28/sign-in-experiences/).  Here they are sending an authentication token, but you can put whatever you want in `channeldata`.  You will need to parse it out in your bot, but it will be available.  This is quite a bit more involved than the WebChat channel, but there isn't currently another way to do it.